# Can I see all transactions not included in a block yet?

Tags: bitcoind, blockchain, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

I'm running `bitcoind` and would like to see which transactions I've received but haven't been included in a block yet. Is that possible, or do I need to run special mining software to see that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The upcoming release of the Bitcoin.org client, version 0.7, includes:

- getrawmempool

Answer (score 1):

You could always check them on Blockchain.info